# Django Async Add to many-to-many field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I am trying to use this piece of code to update a many-to-many field within an async function:

```
async def get_last_message_id() -> int:
    last_message = await Message.objects.all().alast()
    if last_message:
        await last_message.read_by.aadd(request.user)
    return last_message.id if last_message else 0
```

However, I get the following error: `TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable`

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue looks related to calling a synchronous ORM operation (`add` on a [many-to-many field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)) directly from an asynchronous function without using Django's async ORM capabilities or properly adapting the synchronous code to run asynchronously.
Django's ORM does have certain asynchronous capabilities (["Asynchronous support¶"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/async/)), but not all parts of the ORM are fully async-compatible yet.

Given the limitations of Django's async ORM, and the error message you received when using `add` without the `a` prefix (which indicates an attempt to perform a synchronous operation in an async context), the solution should involve using [`sync_to_async` wrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/async/#asgiref.sync.sync_to_async)  from `asgiref.sync` to execute the synchronous code asynchronously.

```py
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

async def get_last_message_id(request) -> int:
    last_message = await Message.objects.all().alast()
    if last_message:
        # Wrap the synchronous add operation in sync_to_async
        await sync_to_async(last_message.read_by.add)(request.user)
    return last_message.id if last_message else 0
```

`sync_to_async(last_message.read_by.add)(request.user)` wraps the synchronous `add` method call in `sync_to_async`: it should enable it to be awaited within an asynchronous function.

But... using `sync_to_async` for individual operations can lead to performance overhead due to the context switch between synchronous and asynchronous execution.

---

> Still getting the same error message, unfortunately. But notice that I did use "aadd" in my code above

Since `aadd` is not a recognized method, the correct approach for asynchronously updating many-to-many relationships should still use `sync_to_async` for synchronous ORM methods.
Or you would need to restructure your code to avoid needing an asynchronous call to `add` directly.

You can try an alternative approach using `sync_to_async`, with a clarification on the execution context:

```py
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

async def get_last_message_id(request) -> int:
    last_message = await Message.objects.all().alast()
    if last_message:
        # Make sure the sync_to_async wrapper is applied correctly
        add_read_by = sync_to_async(last_message.read_by.add, thread_sensitive=True)
        await add_read_by(request.user)
    return last_message.id if last_message else 0
```

The `add_read_by` is a variable that holds the `sync_to_async` wrapped version of the `add` method. That makes it clear that `add_read_by` is an asynchronous function that can be awaited.

Comment: Still getting the same error message, unfortunately. But notice that I did use "aadd" in my code above

Comment: @OhMad OK. I have edited the answer to propose a slight variation. But if it does not work, you would need, as I mention in that edit, to restructure your code to avoid needing an asynchronous call to `add` directly.